# Matlab, finding the variance given a probability distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, matlab, random-variables

How would I numerically find the variance given a probability distribution in MATLAB? I understand(I think) how to do it symbolically, but is there any way to be confirm my results?

I am given the [probability mass function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_mass_function), which is 
$$P(X=n)=2^{-n},\qquad n=1, 2, 3, \ldots$$

Comment: What do you mean by "a function of the RV's probability distribution"? You should write explicitly what you are given.

Comment: I have reworded the entire question. Please check if it is OK.

Comment: do the analytical summation that you solved by hand using a truncated sum for $n = 1, 2, ..., 1000$ (for example)

Answer (score 1):

Use $f(x)$ to obtain a large sample of randomly generated variables $x_i$ which follow this distribution. In case of the normal distribution one could use s = normrnd(mu,sigma,n,m) to create such a sample. Given the vector $s$ containing the sample, you can calculate the variance by var(s). If $f(x)$ is difficult to sample from, you could use a rejection sampler.

Example: s = normrnd(0,1,1,10000) creates a large sample (n=10000) for $X\sim N(0,1)$. This gives var(s)=1.0053.

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding correctly, but how would one go from the probability distribution function to one in which I could obtain a large sample?

Comment: @John, it would help if you could give the specific distribution. If it's normal, binomial, etc. Matlab has built in functions to do this.

Comment: The distribution is 2^-n

Comment: So n is the random variable? What is the domain of the function?

Comment: P(X = n) = 2^-n, all pos. integers

Comment: I am sure (because somebody told me) that you can generate a sample having the prescribed distribution by performing a suitable transformation on a uniform-(0, 1) sample. I just can't figure out what this "suitable transformation" is. Must be something related to the [probability distribution function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function).

Comment: (Nice answer, btw)

Answer (score 1):

According to its definition the variance can be computed from the probability distribution function (BTW is it continuous or discrete, that is, is it a pdf or a pmf?) by integrating the 2nd power of the function minus its expected value.
The [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Definition) has the forumlas for both the continuous and discret case.

In the discrete case it would something like this:
supposing you have the probabilities stored in p and the values in x, sum(p.*(x.^2))-sum(p.*x)^2. But I haven't checked this code.